# UIButton animation ignores target selector in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uibutton, transform, uianimation

I've added this animation code to the end of a function that is called when the button is pushed, but while the animation is happening, it ignores the set target selector until the animation is finished. The animation is very fast, but I'd like users to be able to press it rapidly.

```
        let transforms: CGAffineTransform = .identity

        mirroredButton.transform = transforms

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, animations: {
            mirroredButton.transform = transforms.scaledBy(x: 0.75, y: 0.75)
        },
        completion: { _ in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
                mirroredButton.transform = transforms.scaledBy(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
            }
        })
```

**Update:**

Using the answer, I updated my animation code as shown below. Both animation calls need options. The 2nd has a nil completion handler.

```
        let transforms: CGAffineTransform = .identity

        mirroredButton.transform = transforms

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, delay: 0.0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
            mirroredButton.transform = transforms.scaledBy(x: 0.75, y: 0.75)
        },
        completion: { _ in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
                mirroredButton.transform = transforms.scaledBy(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
            }, completion:nil)
        })
```

Comment: What is it you want the target selector to do? Start the animation over again?

Comment: Yeah that would be fine. I just don't want it to cancel out the ability to trigger the target selector function while it's animating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User interaction is disabled for the duration of a view's animation. If it's critical that the user should interact with a view during an animation, you can pass in the option `.allowUserInteraction`, like so:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
    //animate here
})
```

Comment: Thank you that's it. It's even better with the allowUserInteraction option on the 2nd animate call with a nil completion handler. Updated my code to show this.